# JS: How to pass context to setTimeOut anonymous function which accesses a function class

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow; I have just enough knowledge to have fun with Javascript, but have a bug in everything I write. Please, forgive me if my terminology is wrong.

I just learned that setTimeOut can be used to create multiple timers. So, I wrote a function class to create objects with their own timers. But when I call setTimeout() through a  method of that function class, passing an anonymous function, it seems to not have proper context.  How do I fix this?

I have worked around this issue by writing the function I want performed inside the function class, but this takes away its flexibility.

Below is my (not-so-pretty) working code snippets:

Function class declaration:

```
function sal_clock2 () {
 this.initialized = false;
 var aTimerObject = {timerStarted: false};
 this.holdTimers = [];
 var mythis = this; 
 this.checkIfNotInit = function(index) {
    if (typeof this.holdTimers[index] === "undefined") { //if timer doesn't exist then create it.
      this.holdTimers[index] = {timerStarted: false};
    }
};
 this.setTimeout = function(runFunction, millisecondsDelay) { 
/*runFunction is what I want it to do. Right now it only takes an array index.*/
    //I need the right context so I provide custom "this" by means of "mythis"
    var IDofTimer = setTimeout(function(){mythis.holdTimers[runFunction].timerStarted = false;}, millisecondsDelay);
    return IDofTimer; //returning IDofTimer so that I can reference it later to stop timer if necessary.
}; //end this.setTimeOut
```

}

Usage of sal_clock2 class, when trying to set "enemy do player damage" intervals:

```
var t = new sal_clock2();


for (i = 0; i < $dataMap.events.length; i++) {//do loop to find all enemies so they can attack
if ($dataMap.events[i]) { 
    if ($dataMap.events[i].meta.enemy == "1") { //do enemy attack
        if ($gameMap._events[i]._characterName !== ""){
        if ($gamePlayer._y-1 == $gameMap._events[i]._y && $gamePlayer._x == $gameMap._events[i]._x || // If x is same, and above enemy
            $gamePlayer._y+1 == $gameMap._events[i]._y && $gamePlayer._x == $gameMap._events[i]._x || // If x is same, and below enemy
            $gamePlayer._x-1 == $gameMap._events[i]._x && $gamePlayer._y == $gameMap._events[i]._y || // If y is same, and left of enemy
            $gamePlayer._x+1 == $gameMap._events[i]._x && $gamePlayer._y == $gameMap._events[i]._y) { // If y is same, and right of enemy
                if (!$gameMap.event(i)._sal_unconscious) {//if enemy is not "dead"              

                t.checkIfNotInit(i); //this seems to successfully setup timer for use.

                    if (t.holdTimers[i].timerStarted == false) {
                        t.holdTimers[i].timerStarted = true;
                        t.setTimeout(i,3000); //**//this is my custom setTimeout**
                        //t.setTimeout calls a function defined in function class constructor "sal_clock2", 
                        //which calls JS's setTimeout()
                        $gameActors._data[1]._hp -= 20;
                        $gamePlayer.requestAnimation(1);
                    } //end 
                } //end sal_unconscious check
            } //end coordinate check
        }
    }//end if 
}
```

}

Preferred code call (*opposed to t.setTimeout(i,3000)*):

```
t.setTimeoutTest(function(){t.holdTimers[i].timerStarted = false;}, 3000);
```

My problem is that rather than making the function declaration in the function class constructor I would rather do it here the collision "for loop" found above. But passing an anonymous function does not let me access **t.holdTimers[i].timerStarted = true;** so that I may prevent the function from repeating by means of requestAnimationFrame, instead only repeating at my specified intervals.

Please help, 
An Ignorant Coder

**Edit:**
I apologize for being unclear. I have uploaded some code separated from my collision code, and posted it on github. It has only the bare bones to output value, one working example and one not working. View here: [github](https://github.com/anautodidact/testingCode-stackOverflow/blob/main/setTimout-anonymousFunction-Issue)

I have tried .bind(this) on the anonymous function, but had no success. Passing the object reference "t" to the anonymous function was also unsuccessful. I can't even get a named function to work.

Comment: arrow functions may help

Comment: In answer to your first question - how to pass context. you can call .bind() on it. Like this. myfunction.bind(this);

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What would be useful would be an example of code you've written that isn't working. And if you can separate that out from code that is unrelated to the problem at hand, that would be even more useful.

Comment: In your preferred code, if *t* is an instance of `sal_clock2`, then, even though you're passing an anonymous function to `setTimeoutTest`, *t* used within that function will still hold the same reference to that instance.

Comment: I have tried 
t.setTimeoutTest(function(){t.holdTimers[i].timerStarted = false;}.**bind(this)**, 3000);
but it doesn't work.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear.
I have uploaded some code separated from my collision code, and posted it on github. It has only the bare bones to output value, one working example and one not working.
View here: [link](https://github.com/anautodidact/testingCode-stackOverflow/blob/main/setTimout-anonymousFunction-Issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who gave their insight to my coding problem, I have worked out  what I needed to fix in my code. My understanding of scope, this, and bind needed some adjusting.

To start with, my anonymous function needed to use "this".

```
t.setTimeoutTest(function() {this.holdTimers[i].timerStarted = false;}, 3000);
```

Which seemed misleading to me because "this" would have the wrong context, until I tried the following in the function class's setTimetOutTest function:

```
this.setTimeoutTest = function(runFunction, millisecondsDelay) {
     var IDofTimer = setTimeout(runFunction.bind(this), millisecondsDelay);
}
```

If this were the end of it, I would have marked the above answer correct. But I wasn't so lucky.

Using this code would cause an error which crashed my app. I finally realized that my for loop was programmed for 7 iterations, but that the error was crashing on the 8th. It seems (in my un-expert opinion) that as soon as the 7th iteration finished, it then incremented the index to the 8th. This was a problem because I used the index to reference a variable, but by the time t.setTimeout() called the function the variable had already incremented to an undefined element in the array, causing my code to crash.

I resolved this by saving the index to a variable and using it in my for anonymous function.

```
var myI = i;
t.setTimeoutTest(function() {this.holdTimers[myI].timerStarted = false;}, 3000);
```

Now, my code works as expected and is more robust, although a little unclean. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `mythis` in the wrong scope. Like other languages such as Java and C++, local variables in javascript are not accessible outside the scope of the function they are defined in. So define `mythis` in the correct scope:

```
function sal_clock2 () {
 this.initialized = false;
 var aTimerObject = {timerStarted: false};
 this.holdTimers = [];
 // var mythis = this; // <----- WRONG PLACE, remove this
 this.checkIfNotInit = function(index) {
    if (typeof this.holdTimers[index] === "undefined") { //if timer doesn't exist then create it.
      this.holdTimers[index] = {timerStarted: false};
    }
};


this.setTimeout = function(runFunction, millisecondsDelay) { 

    var mythis = this; // <----- you need to capture `this` HERE

    var IDofTimer = setTimeout(function(){mythis.holdTimers[runFunction].timerStarted = false;}, millisecondsDelay);
    return IDofTimer; //returning IDofTimer so that I can reference it later to stop timer if necessary.
}; //end this.setTimeOut
```

However, modern javascript have features that you can use to avoid `this` aliasing/caching:

#### Arrow functions statically capture scope:

```
this.setTimeout = function(runFunction, millisecondsDelay) { 

    // PASS AN ARROW FUNCTION to setTimeout:

    var IDofTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.holdTimers[runFunction].timerStarted = false; // no need mythis
    }, millisecondsDelay);

    return IDofTimer;

};
```

#### Functions can also be manually bound to a specific `this`:

```
this.setTimeout = function(runFunction, millisecondsDelay) {

    var callback = function () {
        this.holdTimers[runFunction].timerStarted = false; // no need mythis
    }

    // Manually binding the callback function allow you to pass any `this`
    // you want to it:
    var IDofTimer = setTimeout(callback.bind(this), millisecondsDelay);

    return IDofTimer;

};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I have marked your answer helpful but since I have less than 15 reputation points it doesn't change the indicator.

Your suggestions helped me, although they didn't resolve my issues, they have helped me grasp these concepts as they relate to _my code_, as opposed to random Internet sample code.